# Rails Devise, how to skip the confirmation email but still generate a confirmation token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using

```
      user.skip_confirmation!
```

To skip the devise email confirmation when a new user is added by an existing user. The problem with the skip_confirmation is that it does not generate a confirmation token.

I want to manually send a confirmation email which means I need a confirmation token.

How can I skip the devise confirmation email yet still generate a confirmaton_token to allow me to manually send a custom confirmation email to added users?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [confirmable.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb). In particular, around line 253 - 256. I think that should help you out.

In short:

```
module Devise
  module Models
    module Confirmable
      module ClassMethods
        # Generate a token checking if one does not already exist in the database.
        def confirmation_token
          generate_token(:confirmation_token)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 20):

```
@user = User.new(:email => 'email@example.com', :password => 'password') 
@user.skip_confirmation_notification!
@user.save
```

Here **skip_confirmation_notification!** generate a confirmation token but does not send confirmation email.