# Devise: Remove confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using ng-token-auth with devise-token-auth.

This is my user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable,
         :validatable, :omniauthable

  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
end
```

I don't have confirmable listed but everytime I try to register, it tries to send a confirmation email and when I try to login, it says I have to follow the instructions in the email. How can I remove this? I went through the documentation and some posts, I thought that only happens when I have :confirmable in the user.rb. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706101/rails-devise-how-to-skip-the-confirmation-email-but-still-generate-a-confirmati

Comment: i read about skip_confirmation!. Is that the only way? I just want the user to be able to simply register and be logged in, I am surprised it doesn't let me do that by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [issue#99](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/releases) in devise_token_auth issue tracker described problem with Confirmable module occurs in versions under 0.1.30 So the possible fix is to upgrade gem version and it should works.
Other fix for versions 0.1.30 and below is to actually skip confirmation callback

```
before_save -> { skip_confirmation! }
```

P.S. I think that better to not delete my previous answer because of comments section.

Answer (score 1):

That's strange that your code doesn't work as it pretty close to devise_token_auth documentation example. 
However maybe this Devise hint helps you:

Add to User model this method

```
protected
def confirmation_required?
  false
end
```

Taken from Devise wiki: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users#allowing-unconfirmed-access

Hope, it will help you!

Comment: i'm getting NameError - undefined local variable or method `confirmed_at' now

Comment: I guess it not helps because you don't have required fields for this module (as you don't use it). However I have other clue about your error. What version of devise_token_auth do you use?

Comment: Using devise_token_auth 0.1.30

Comment: def confirmed_at
        DateTime.now
    end
    def confirmed_at=(val)
    end

    def unconfirmed_email
        self.email
    end
    def unconfirmed_email=(val)
    end

Comment: i did that and was able to bypass the confirmation but when i try to log in, i get undefined method `current_sign_in_at', but i don't have trackable on either, im so confused

Comment: I've found this issue https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/99 So maybe upgrading gem helps you to achieve what you want. Or according to this issue https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/253 try to skip validations